# Verilog 4bit X 4bit add and shift multiplier

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, multiplication

I'm trying to make a 4bit X 4bit multiplier in Verilog that uses the add and shift method.  However, when I run the simulation, I keep getting 00 for the `result` value.

This is the code that I used:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module multi_8bit(
    input clk,
    input rstn,
    input start,
    input [3:0] a,
    input [3:0] b,
    output reg [7:0] result,
    output reg done
    );
   
    localparam IDLE = 3'b000,
                START = 3'b001,
                LSB = 3'b010,
                ADD = 3'b011,
                SHIFT = 3'b100,
                DONE = 3'b101;
   
    reg [2:0] state, next_state;
    reg [7:0] r_multiplicant;
    reg [7:0] r_product;
    reg [3:0] r_multiplier;
    reg [2:0] r_count;
   
    always @(posedge clk, negedge rstn)
    begin
        if(!rstn)
        begin
            state <= IDLE;
        end
        else
        begin
            state <= START;
        end
    end
   
    always@(*)
    begin
        case(state)
            IDLE:
            begin
                if(start)
                    next_state = START;
                else
                    next_state = IDLE;
            end
           
            START:
            begin
                if(r_count != 0)
                    next_state = LSB;
                else
                    next_state = DONE;
            end
           
            LSB:
            begin
                if(b[0])
                    next_state = ADD;
                else
                    next_state = SHIFT;
            end
           
            ADD:
            begin
                next_state = SHIFT;
            end
           
            SHIFT:
            begin
                next_state = START;
            end
           
            DONE:
            begin
                next_state <= IDLE;
            end
        endcase
    end
   
    always@(posedge clk, negedge rstn)
    begin
        if(!rstn)
        begin
            r_multiplicant <= 0;
            r_multiplier <= 0;
            r_product <= 0;
            r_count <= 4;
            result <= 0;
            done <= 0;
        end
        else
        begin
            begin
                case(state)
                    IDLE:
                    begin
                        
                    end
                        
                    START:
                    begin
                        r_multiplicant = a;
                        r_multiplier = b;
                    end
                        
                    LSB:
                    begin
                        r_count <= r_count - 1;
                    end
                        
                    ADD:
                    begin
                        r_product <= r_product + r_multiplicant;
                    end
                        
                    SHIFT:
                    begin
                        r_multiplicant <= r_multiplicant << 1;
                        r_multiplier <= r_multiplier >> 1;
                    end
                        
                    DONE:
                    begin
                        assign result = r_product;
                    end
                endcase
            end
        end
    end

   
endmodule
```

And this is the testbench code that I used:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module tb_multi_8bit();

    reg clk;
    reg rstn;
    reg start;
    reg [3:0] a;
    reg [3:0] b;
    
    wire [7:0] result;

    always #10 clk = ~clk;
    
    multi_8bit test(
        .clk(clk),
        .rstn(rstn),
        .start(start),
        .a(a),
        .b(b),
        .result(result)
    );

    initial
    begin
        clk = 0; rstn = 1; start = 0;
        #15 rstn = 0;
        #25 rstn = 1;
        #20 start = 1;
        #10 a[0] = 0; a[1] = 1; a[2] = 1; a[3] = 0; 
        b[0] = 0; b[1] = 0; b[2] = 0; b[3] = 1; 
        #20 a[0] = 0; a[1] = 1; a[2] = 1; a[3] = 0; 
        b[0] = 0; b[1] = 0; b[2] = 1; b[3] = 0; 
        #20 a[0] = 0; a[1] = 1; a[2] = 1; a[3] = 0; 
        b[0] = 0; b[1] = 0; b[2] = 0; b[3] = 1; 
        
        #20 $finish;
    end

endmodule
```

I just started learning Verilog and this is my first time using the shift function, so I have no idea where I made a mistake in the code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the sequential logic of your state machine.  After reset, you force the state to always be `START`, but you should set it to `next_state`.  This was obvious when I looked at waveforms of your internal signals.

This allows the state machine to progress through other states:

```
always @(posedge clk, negedge rstn)
begin
    if(!rstn)
    begin
        state <= IDLE;
    end
    else
    begin
        state <= next_state;
    end
end
```

Also, I added more delay before you end the simulation to see more states:

```
    #50 $finish;
```

The `result` remains at 0 because the state machine never reaches the `DONE` state where you update the result.  You need to look at waveforms to understand why you never reach that state.